# Deserialize nested JSON to SObject and get keySet

Tags: apex, json

I have two different requests as below that will hit same end point. I need to identify the request body based on the nested attributes. Now if the key attribute contacts must be same for both payloads which makes it difficult to identify which payload is coming to salesforce.

```
Payload 1:

{ 
    "contacts":[{
            "recIds":["23233232322323","092309340932p"],
            "contact":"23wes"
        },{
            "recIds":["983298dwjhe209"],
            "contact":"feoir3nk"
        }]

}
```

```
payload 2:
{ 
    "contacts":[

            {
                "emailID" : "test@email.com",
                "action" : "update",
                "phoneNumber":"110000422997"
            },
            {
                "emailID" : "test2@email.com",
                "action" : "update",
                "phoneNumber":"110000422887"
            }
        ]

}
```

Is there a way I can add the keys of nested attributes to a set(for example: {'recIds','reason'}) so I can check if the string 'recIds' contains in the request object and identify the appropriate payload?

```
deserializedMap = (Map<String,object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(payload);
List<Object> ideals = (List<Object>) deserializedMap.get('contacts');
```

List ideals is returning something like

```
[reason=uh, contact=23wes]
```

But I just need list or set for just keys.

Comment: Is it possible for you to set up a second endpoint, and have your external system send to different endpoints per payload format? It wouldn't need to be anything fancy. `@RestResource(urlMapping='/my/event/*')` (with a wildcard at the end) would allow a single class (in Apex) to handle calls to `/my/event/1` and `/my/event/2`.

Answer (score 0):

Since both requests are lists of objects; you could deserialize into a custom apex type that looked like:

```
class Payload {
  String[] recIds;
  String contact;
  String emailId;
  String action;
  String phoneNumber;
}
```

and then deserialize into a variable

```
 Payload[] contacts;
```

The presence of null value in `emailId` says it is `Payload1`; the presence of null value in contact indicates `Payload2`.